# Regex string ends with not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not very familiar with regex. I was trying to test if a string ends with another string. The code below returns null when I was expecting true. What's wrong with the code?

```
var id = "John";
var exists  ="blahJohn".match(/id$/);
alert(exists);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Well, with this approach, you would need to use the [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp), to build a regular expression using your `id` variable:

```
var id = "John";
var exists = new RegExp(id+"$").test("blahJohn");
alert(exists);
```

But there are plenty ways to achieve that, for example, you can take the last `id.length` characters of the string, and compare it with `id`:

```
var id = "John";
var exist = "blahJohn".slice(-id.length) == id; // true
```

Answer (score 9):

You would need to use a `RegExp()` object to do that, not a literal:

```
var id = "John",
    reg = new RegExp(id+"$");

alert( reg.test("blahJon") );
```

That is, if you do not know the value you are testing for ahead of runtime. Otherwise you could do:

```
alert( /John$/.test("blahJohn") );
```

Comment: Should be /John$/.test("blahJohn")

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
var reg = "/" + id + "$/";
var exists  ="blahJohn".match(reg);
```

Comment: @Tony - Why doesn't this work? Can you explain please? I think this should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The nicer way to do this is to use `RegExp.test`:

```
(new RegExp(id + '$')).test('blahJohn'); // true
(new RegExp(id + '$')).test('blahJohnblah'); // false
```

Even nicer would be to build a simple function like this:

```
function strEndsWith (haystack, needle) {
    return needle === haystack.substr(0 - needle.length);
}

strEndsWith('blahJohn', id); // true
strEndsWith('blahJohnblah', id); // false
```

Comment: The `substr` method on IE < 9 is buggy, it cannot handle negative indices, e.g., testing: `'abc'.substr(-1) == 'c'` fails, IE's `substr` returns the whole string. I would recommend the `slice` instead. Cheers.

Comment: @CMS Thanks. I won't change it, since your answer is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = new RegExp("John");
var exists  ="blahJohn".match(id);
alert(exists);
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

I like @lonesomeday 's solution, but Im fan of extending the String.prototype in these scenarios. Here's my adaptation of his solution

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function (needle) {
     return needle === this.substr(0 - needle.length);
}
```

So can be checked with

```
if(myStr.endsWith("test")) // Do awesome things here.
```

Tasty...

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = "John";

(new RegExp(`${id}$`)).test('blahJohn');  // true
(new RegExp(`${id}$`)).test('blahJohna'); // false
```

`${id}$` is a JavaScript [Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) which will be compiled to 'John$'.

The `$` after John in RegExp stands for **end of string** so the tested string must not have anything after id value (i.e. John) in order to pass the test.

new RegExp(`${id}$`) - will compile it to `/John$/` (so if id shouldn't be dynamic you can use just /John$/ instead of new RegExp(`${id}$`) )

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Cool, done :). Hope the explanation I"ve added helps to understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why using RegExp? Its expensive.

```
function EndsWith( givenStr, subst )
{
var ln = givenStr.length;
var idx = ln-subst.length;
return ( giventStr.subst(idx)==subst );
}
```

Much easier and cost-effective, is it?

Comment: @StewieGriffin that's the whole point, your answer is incorrect

Comment: `Why using RegExp? Its expensive.` Um, maybe for all the benefits regexp brings. Your function doesn't work: `EndsWith("Foobar Baz", /baz|test|\d\d-\d\d-202\d/i);`

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for replace function, consider this regExp:

```
var eventStr = "Hello% World%";

eventStr = eventStr.replace(/[\%]$/, "").replace(/^[\%]/, ""); // replace eds with, and also start with %.
```

//output: eventStr = "Hello% World";

Answer (score 0):

## 2022, ECMA 11

Just created this helper function, I find it more useful and clean than modifying the regex and recreating one everytime.

```js
/**
 * @param {string} str 
 * @param {RegExp} search 
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function regexEndsWith (str, search, {caseSensitive = true} = {})
{
    var source = search.source
    if (!source.endsWith('$')) source = source + '$'
    var flags = search.flags
    if (!caseSensitive && !flags.includes('i')) flags += 'i'
    var reg = new RegExp(source, flags)
    return reg.test(str)
}
```

Use it this way:

```js
regexEndsWith('can you Fi    nD me?', /fi.*nd me?/, {caseSensitive: false})
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a string prototype function that utilizes regex. You can use it to check if any string object ends with a particular string value:

**Prototype function:**

```
String.prototype.endsWith = function (endString) {
    if(this && this.length) {
        result = new RegExp(endString + '$').test(this);
        return result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
var s1 = "My String";
s1.endsWith("ring"); // returns true;
s1.endsWith("deez"); //returns false;
```

Comment: You should explain why this answers the question.